# Being paid less than what I was promised

Tags: software-industry, salary

I gave an interview in a company and there they claimed that we would give you what you demand with 10% increment every 6 months. I agreed and joined the company as a tech lead. It has been 2 weeks now and I have been given a draft of a would be contract in which I am being paid 25% less with 10% increment per year.

The CEO iterated the salary as Base Gross Salary when I inquired about the salary which is clearly hocus pocus so what should I reply with?

**Update 1**

I am in Pakistan, here laws don't matter much. I have signed an offer letter which mentions everything correctly. I did an email to the CEO yesterday mentioning it and haven't heard from him since.

The probation period is 3 months so actually its far from. If I do resign, will there be a negative effect on my career or should I just hide this fact in other job interviews?

**Update 2**

Well the CEO agreed to better terms than previously agreed upon after an intense back and forth of emails and many misunderstandings. Well at the end, a face to face meeting was all that was necessary when I gave away a hint that I'll be quitting the same day if he didn't provide a plausible reason for this (Thanks Kilisi).

Comment: Why didn't you have a signed contract _before_ you joined?

Comment: @JaneS In my country, contracts are signed after probation period expires as a standard practice. Before that an offer letter is given and signed. Mine contained the values presented in the interview.

Comment: Seems open ended. Where is this? Was 2 weeks the probationary period? Do you have anything from the interview period in writing that would indicate this pay scale? Sounds like you either got tricked or didn't read the fine print. Nevertheless, it's only been 2 weeks...and your pay scale is adjusting...is this an industry norm?

Comment: if you don't have a written contract signed by you and the employer representative, showing your gross or net salary per month or per year, you can do one of two things : 1. accept the status quo and keep working as usual; 2. Pack up and leave. You do not have any other leverage unfortunately.

Comment: What country is this in? Though unless you have the promise in writing and are willing to take them to court or threatening to publicize this -- either of which is a "career-limiting action" --you have no leverage and all you can do is try to look for an honest employer. If you don't have the promise in writing, you have absolutely nothing to work with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Comment: If you actually got 10% every 6 months, then they would be trying to get rid of you after a few years when they realised how expensive that became.  10% per 6 months compounded up represents a huge wage inflation - around 6.7x your starting salary after 10 years, 45x your starting salary after 20 years.

Comment: If it's usual to get a contract only after probation, it might also be usual to explain what happened to a next employer? ("I left as the actual contract they offered me during probation was much worse than what the signed offer letter stated")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should get out while you can, you don't seem to have any leverage to force the employer.

One thing about countries where you have little power in employment, is that this sort of issue doesn't usually impact on other job prospects. In any case you should seriously think about cutting your losses now. At the very least a resignation will either lead to a better resolution, or get you out where you can look for a better employer.